# SQL openXML How to use for loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is my code I have problem in inserting the xml element values one by one..
How to put for loop for this

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(8000)
SET @x = 
  '<authors>
    <author>
        <firstname>Michael</firstname>
        <lastname>Howard</lastname>
    </author>
    <author>
        <firstname>David</firstname>
        <lastname>LeBlanc</lastname>
    </author>
    <author>
        <firstname>adad</firstname>
        <lastname>asdad</lastname>
    </author>
     <author>
        <firstname>adad</firstname>
        <lastname>asdad</lastname>
    </author>
   </authors>'

DECLARE @h INT
DECLARE @h1 VARCHAR(MAX)
EXECUTE sp_xml_preparedocument @h OUTPUT, @x 

SELECT @h1= firstname 
FROM OPENXML(@h, '/authors/author',2)
WITH(
    firstname VARCHAR(20)

)
select NAME from temps WHERE NAME=@h1 
if @@ROWCOUNT=0
Begin
INSERT INTO temps(NAME)  VALUES (@h1)
END
EXECUTE sp_xml_removedocument @h
```

Now my code is inserting only last xml element I want to do it one after the another.. tell me the solution or idea

Comment: You have described what you are doing, but not *why* you are doing it or what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Why do you want to do it this way?  the sp_xml_preparedocument is deprecated; are you still using SQL 2000, or are you open to using other methods?  Also, why do you only wnat to inser one element at a time?

Comment: Check my code now.. i want to check some condition so i thought of doing like this.. or suggest me good idea.. i use 2008 server..

Answer (score 1):

```
 DECLARE @x XML  = '<authors>
  <author>
    <firstname>Michael</firstname>
    <lastname>Howard</lastname>
  </author>
  <author>
    <firstname>David</firstname>
    <lastname>LeBlanc</lastname>
  </author>
  <author>
    <firstname>adad</firstname>
    <lastname>asdad</lastname>
  </author>
  <author>
    <firstname>adad</firstname>
    <lastname>asdad</lastname>
  </author>
</authors>'

 SELECT T.c.value('./firstname[1]', 'varchar(200)')
 FROM @x.nodes('/authors/author') AS T(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not described *why* you are processing the XML, so I will guess. It appears you are looking for a specific `firstname` value in the `temps` table and if it is not found then you add it. I'll demonstrate with a table variable, `@names`.

```
-- Assume you have a table [temps] with
-- a column [name], and you want to find
-- the new/missing firstnames from an XML
-- fragment and insert the new firstnames into
-- the [temps] table
-- Example:
--DECLARE [temps] TABLE (name VARCHAR(20))
--INSERT [temps] (name) VALUES ('Michael')

-- Create a temporary table to hold the XML firstname values
DECLARE @names TABLE (firstname VARCHAR(20))
DECLARE @x xml
SET @x =  
  '<authors> 
    <author> 
        <firstname>Michael</firstname> 
        <lastname>Howard</lastname> 
    </author> 
    <author> 
        <firstname>David</firstname> 
        <lastname>LeBlanc</lastname> 
    </author> 
    <author> 
        <firstname>adad</firstname> 
        <lastname>asdad</lastname> 
    </author> 
     <author> 
        <firstname>adad</firstname> 
        <lastname>asdad</lastname> 
    </author> 
   </authors>' 

-- Extract the firstnames from the XML and insert the names
-- into the temp table variable
INSERT INTO @names(firstname)
SELECT  x.author.value('firstname[1]', 'varchar(20)') AS firstname
FROM    @x.nodes('/authors/author') AS x(author)

-- Use a left outer join query to identify the new/missing names
-- in the temp table and then insert the names into [temps].
-- The WHERE condition specifies rows that exist in @firstnames
-- but do not exist (are NULL) in [temps].
INSERT  temps (name)
SELECT  nam.firstname
FROM    @names      nam  LEFT OUTER JOIN
        temps       tmp  ON (nam.firstname = tmp.name)
WHERE   tmp.name IS NULL
```

The LEFT OUTER JOIN is used with a WHERE condition to identity firstnames that are in the @firstnames table variable and not in the [firstnames] table. Whenever possible try to avoid iterating through data in SQL and try to use set based operations.

Comment: yes... i want to take one value at a time in @name and that i have to check in 2 or 3 table.. so can u pls tel me how can i check in above example..

Comment: again i don't want to do select all

Comment: What do you need to check in 2 or 3 tables? Whether the name exists in other tables? You can almost always do this with set based operations which are almost always a better way of doing things with SQL rather than iterating one by one. Please provide more detail about what you are doing in the 2 or 3 other tables.

Comment: i want to check whether its exist in other 2 tables...by taking the foreign key of one table and i wanna check in others..

Comment: i'm looking for a specific firstname value in the temps table and if it is not found then i want to insert it otherwise go to next value and want to repeat the same.. now you are clear i think...

Comment: I have added an example of a LEFT OUTER JOIN query with INSERT. This allows you to insert new or missing items without using a cursor. Try to avoid cursors unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you do something like this:

```
 DECLARE @x xml
SET @x = 
  '<authors>
    <author>
        <firstname>Michael</firstname>
        <lastname>Howard</lastname>
    </author>
    <author>
        <firstname>David</firstname>
        <lastname>LeBlanc</lastname>
    </author>
    <author>
        <firstname>adad</firstname>
        <lastname>asdad</lastname>
    </author>
     <author>
        <firstname>adad</firstname>
        <lastname>asdad</lastname>
    </author>
   </authors>'

SELECT 
  ref.value('firstname[1]', 'NVARCHAR(20)') AS firstname ,
  ref.value('lastname[1]', 'NVARCHAR (10)') AS lastname ,
  ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ref.value('firstname[1]', 'NVARCHAR(20)')) AS rownum 

FROM @x.nodes('/authors/author') 
xmlData( ref )

Which prints: 
firstname            lastname   rownum
-------------------- ---------- --------------------
adad                 asdad      1
adad                 asdad      2
David                LeBlanc    3
Michael              Howard     4
```

You can easily do an `insert into ...` instead of doing a loop

**NOTE** I added row_num because it looked like you only wanted to insert the second row's value from what I understood from your query

Answer (score 0):

> Got The Answer.........

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(8000),
        @nItemCnt int
DECLARE @ProductID VARCHAR(MAX),
        @lcnt INT
DECLARE @@getCurrentName CURSOR,
@h INT,
@h1 VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @x = 
  '<authors>
    <author>
        <firstname>Michael</firstname>
        <lastname>Howard</lastname>
    </author>
    <author>
        <firstname>David</firstname>
        <lastname>LeBlanc</lastname>
    </author>
    <author>
        <firstname>adad</firstname>
        <lastname>asdad</lastname>
    </author>
     <author>
        <firstname>adad</firstname>
        <lastname>asdad</lastname>
    </author>
   </authors>'


EXECUTE sp_xml_preparedocument @h OUTPUT, @x 
SET @@getCurrentName = CURSOR FOR SELECT firstname FROM OPENXML(@h, '/authors/author',2)WITH(firstname VARCHAR(20))
OPEN @@getCurrentName
FETCH NEXT FROM @@getCurrentName INTO @ProductID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
select @lcnt=COUNT(name) from temps WHERE name=@ProductID
if @lcnt=0 
insert into temps values(@ProductID)
PRINT @ProductID
FETCH NEXT
FROM @@getCurrentName INTO @ProductID
END
CLOSE @@getCurrentName
DEALLOCATE @@getCurrentName
```